# Remove checkbox from QTableView items

Tags: qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I want to implement a table filled with data via QTableView. My problem is that I don't know how to remove the checkboxes from the cells. It seems like they are put in by default.

However, I read that I had to return a NULL-QVariant, but that's not what I was looking for as I still have data to put in.

```cpp
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    int row = index.row();
    int col = index.column();
    QString daten;
    
    switch (col)
    {
    case 0:
    {
        daten = "column 1";
        break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        daten = "column 2";
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        daten = "column 3";
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        daten = "column 4";
        break;
    }
    }
    
    return daten;
}
```

Now, as you can see, I want to fill the cell with the QString called `daten`. But next to the string, there is a Checkbox in every cell.

How do I remove the checkbox, but still fill the content with `daten`?

Comment: in your `data`, you should (1) take into account the case where `index` is invalid and (2) make sure you check for the role before returning `data` (it should be `Qt.DisplayRole` for a basic display).

Comment: ok, thanks, that works! could you please explain what effect these lines have?

Comment: Which lines are you referring to?

Comment: well, the ones you told me to add:

if (!index.isValid())
    return QVariant();
if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
    return QVariant();

Comment: I made a proper answer that should address your question. We can always edit it with more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the cells in your `QTableView` have some checkbox hint that they were defined as user-checkable. Check whether you don't have a `Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable` flag activated somewhere in the definition of your `QTableView`, and if that's the case, deactivate it. You could try to modify the `flags` method, for example, forcing every entry *not* to be checkable

As an additional comment, you should probably modify your `::data` method to take into account the case where `index` is invalid and to return some value only if the role corresponds to `Qt.DisplayRole`. In Python, the syntax would be

```
if index.isvalid():
    if (role == Qt.DisplayRole):
        (row, col) = (index.row(), index.column()
        return_something_depending_on_col
    return QVariant()
return QVariant()
```

That way, you cover the case of an invalid index, your code would likely crash otherwise.

The test on `role` allows you to choose which type of data you want to access. The [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) states for example that:

> Each item in the model has a set of data elements associated with it, each with its own role. The roles are used by the view to indicate to the model which type of data it needs. Custom models should return data in these types.

The basic role is `Qt.DisplayRole`, where you return the `QString` corresponding to your current cell. You could also return a `QBrush` for painting the background if your role is `Qt.BackgroundRole`...

While not mandatory, these tests on `role` are still highly encouraged: it makes your code cleaner and easier to maintain.