# How to get rid of unwanted rounded squares (checkboxes) in QTableView items?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel, qtwidgets

I have a `QTableView` with some data (numbers), but each cell contains an unwanted rounded square (maybe a non-functional checkbox). They look bad, occupy space, and can obscure my data.

Why do they appear? How can I remove them?

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QHeaderView>

class MyModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
public:
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex& index) const override {return 5;}
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex& index) const override {return 2;}
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const override
    {
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
            return 3000 + index.row() * 100 + index.column();
        else
            return 0;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow w;
    QTableView widget;
    MyModel model;
    widget.setModel(&model);
    widget.horizontalHeader()->hide();
    widget.verticalHeader()->hide();
    w.setCentralWidget(&widget);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image: Window]

I use Qt 6.8.0 on Windows 11.

Comment: Try `return QVariant();` in place of `return 0` in `MyModel::data()`.  You are in effect returning `Qt::Unckecked` for `Qt::CheckStateRole`, which is a signal to render a checkbox.

Comment: The "rounded squares" are check boxes, and they are just a symptom of a wrong implementation. You're just lucky that Qt item views and their delegates just ignore unacceptable values, a more strict system would have thrown an exception. What `data()` returns can be used for lots of other aspects that obviously cannot accept `0` as a value, like fonts, size hints, background/foreground colors, tooltips, etc. See the docs about the [`Qt.ItemDataRole`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) and the expected value types in their description. `0` is a number, a quite specific type.

Comment: The documentation is quite clear: you should always return an invalid `QVariant()` for any role/index/value exception that doesn't explicitly return the expected type of that role, so, please read more carefully the [Qt Model/View Programming Guide](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html) (specifically, the [model headers and data](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html#model-headers-and-data) section, but don't underestimate all the rest), as everything is clearly explained there.

Comment: [Remove checkbox from QTableView items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197044/qt-qabstractmodel-remove-checkbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`QAbstractItemModel::data()` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) states:

> Note: If you do not have a value to return, return an invalid (default-constructed) `QVariant`.

There are [many roles](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) defined, but you are only looking for `Qt::DisplayRole` and then you are returning `0` for all the rest.  Chances are, you are being queried for `Qt::CheckStateRole` and thus returning a "false" checked state for it, which would explain why the check boxes appear.

> Roles describing appearance and meta data (with associated types):
>
> | Constant | Value | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | ... | ... | ... |
> | Qt::CheckStateRole | 10 | This role is used to obtain the checked state of an item. (Qt::CheckState) |
> | ... | ... | ... |

So, do what the documentation says - return an empty `QVariant` instead:

```
QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const override
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        return 3000 + index.row() * 100 + index.column();
    else
        // return 0;
        return QVariant(); // <-- HERE
}
```

Comment: It's not just the `CheckStateRole`: Qt views and delegates are "smart enough" to ignore unacceptable values, but there are limits. A clear example is the text alignment of the items, which is then assumed as a "literal 0" and therefore considered as a `Qt.Alignment` value, leading to a top center alignment, as shown in the screenshot: the center is arbitrarily set (no explicit hint about the layout direction), the top is arbitrarily assumed by the delegate and the style.